# Creating Shape with Google Apps Script in Google Sheets

Tags: image, google-apps-script, shapes, google-sheets-api

I have a Google apps script that creates a new tab, which is executed through a shape that I added; more specifically a bevel. Now I would like for that same macro to create a new bevel shape on that new tab and assign it a new script.

How do I create a shape via GAS, and then assign a new script to it?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

There are functions for inserting images. However there is no way to attach a script to them except for manually.

There are also no functions for getting, deleting, or otherwise manipulating an image once it is [art of the sheet. This prevents copying the an existing image. You would need to source your image from a URL or by providing a blob (sort of like file contents) probably pulled from a file in drive.

You may want to consider using a custom menu:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getUi()

Comment: Or a custom sidebar, served via HtmlService. Sidebars would allow for a "persistently visible" button, etc.

Comment: A custom menu is definitely an option, but requires an additional click I am trying to avoid (as I will have to execute this function hundreds of times). Thus, do you know of a way to perhaps copy the shape over to the new tab? OR, is there a way to script the button to make it run one command on the first click and then when you click it again it does the opposite? (Ex: first click it creates a new tab, second click it deletes the new tab). Thanks!

Comment: added a bit to the answer to cover the copying aspect. 

as for making a the button do two things that should probably be its own question. In short yes, using an if statement either evaluating the existence of a particular named tab or some value stored using the Properties service.